# Different time values for same field

Tags: typescript, types, primeng

```
<form>
 <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="report.incidentTime" [showTime]="true" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [maxDate]="maxDateValue"
                                (ngModelChange)="validateTime($event)"></p-calendar>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ripple" (click)="saveReport()" >Save</button>

</form>
```

Here using primeNg calendar for displaying calendar.

```
saveReport() {
        console.log("Inside save");
        this.validateFields();

        let temp = this.report;
        console.log("Time : "+this.report.incidentTime);
        console.log("Object :  "+JSON.stringify(this.report));

}
```

where as  **incidentTime: Date;**, is atype of Date.

```
Time: Mon Oct 02 2017 09:34:39 GMT+0400 (Arabian Standard Time)
Object :  {"incidentTime":"2017-10-02T05:34:39.000Z","reportingType":"I"}
```

Here two output is giving different time. Why is this ?
How can I get the same time in Object also. instead og giving 4 hrs less.

Comment: it's the same time it's just the fact that one is in the local timezone while the other is in GMT? the time difference seems right

Comment: Do I need to add the timezone after than and calculate the current time ?

Answer (score 0):

It's the same date, it's just that the p-calender component converts it to UTC from GMT+4.

You can control this behaviour with the **utc** attribute.

You can see the documentation [here](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar).

Comment: Tried that solution, already saw that attribute in doc, it doesn't have any effect. prime ng version 2.0.0

Comment: maybe it's because of this issue? https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/3611